# Order a numeric vector by length in R

Tags: r

I've got two numeric vectors that I want to *order by the length* of the their observations, i.e., the number of times each observation appears.

For example:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "e", "e")
```

Here, `b` occurs four times, `a` three times, `e` two and `c` one time. I'd like my result in this order.

```
ans <- c("b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "e", "e", "c")
```

I´ve tried this:

```
x <- x[order(-length(x))] # and some similar lines.
```

Thanks

Comment: Are your vector's same elements always consecutive? If not, you could `tmp = sort(table(x)); rep(names(tmp), tmp)` (similar to @agstudy 's answer). `table` should be pretty fast, too, nonetheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `rle` you can get values lenghts. You order lengths,  and use  values to recreate the vector again using the new order:

```
xx <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','b', 'c', 'e', 'e')
rr <- rle(xx)
ord <- order(rr$lengths,decreasing=TRUE)
rep(rr$values[ord],rr$length[ord])

## [1] "b" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "e" "e" "c"
```

Comment: Didn't know about this one, [here is the rle documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html)

Answer (score 5):

You may also use `ave` when calculating the `length`s

```
x[order(ave(x, x, FUN = length), decreasing = TRUE)]
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "e" "e" "c"
```